# Python TCP socket timeout what happen after timeout is reached? Does it properly close the socket?

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, timeout

He||o,

I made a simple TCP server and client.

The server waits forever to get a client to connect, once a client is connected, if no data is received for 5 seconds it timeout. To do so, I put the timeout on the conn, not the socket.
The client sends what you type in the terminal.

When the server reach a timeout, what happends to conn? Is it closed properly or should I call conn.close() ?

client.py :

```
import socket

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST = '1.2.3.4'          # The remote host, put your own ip address
    PORT = 50053              # The same port as used by the server
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
        s.connect((HOST, PORT))
        print(f"Connected to {HOST} {PORT}")
        while(True):
            toBeSent = input("Enter the int to be doubled :")
            s.sendall(str.encode(toBeSent))
            print(f"Finished")
            if toBeSent == "shutdown":
                break   #exit if we sent shutdown
```

server.py :

```
import socket, os

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #host = socket.gethostname() #Could also just put (host = ''), it gets the local machine 
    host = '0.0.0.0'
    port = 50053
    with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:  #if no parram, 1st param is socket.AF_INET and 2nd is  socket.SOCK_STREAM
        s.bind((host, port))
        print(f"Server (host : {host}) (port : {port}) (pid : {os.getpid()}) listening....")
        s.listen()
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('\tConnected by address :', addr)
            while True:
                conn.settimeout(5)
                data = conn.recv(1024).decode()
                conn.settimeout(None)
                if data == "shutdown" :
                    conn.close()
                    break
                print(f"\t\tReceived {data}")
```

Note : I can also send "shutdown" to stop the process.

Thanks in adavance for your answers.

Comment: Call `.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you set a timeout, socket operations, like `send` and `recv`, will not block indefinitely but raise an exception when the timeout elapses.

When the timeout exception occurs, the socket connection is not closed and you can perform other operations on it. You have to call `shutdown` and `close` yourself when you are done with the socket connection.

The timeout allows you to do "other work" while sending and receiving data.